# Customization of Navigation menu in Wordpress

Tags: menu, wordpress-theming, wordpress, navigationbar

I'm new in Wordpress. I run the wordpress using xampp. Themes have a limited navigatiob menu, and I want to add two to four navigation menus with sub-menus in my theme. How can I do that? What file should I edit to add some navigation menus?

Please help me.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your theme `functions.php` you should register the menu location by adding the following code:

```
register_nav_menus(
    array(
        'menu_1' => 'Menu name #1',
        'menu_2' => 'Menu name #2'
    )
);
```

For more instruction about the `register_nav_menus()` function you can visit the related **[codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_nav_menus)**.

Then in your theme files, you should use the following code:

```
wp_nav_menu(
    array(
        'menu' => 'menu_1'
    )
);
```

For more instructions about the `wp_nav_menu()` function you can visit the related **[codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu)**.

Finally, the sub menu items can be manipulated from within the WordPress dashboard. You can see this [**video**](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b_Tn5c_IbRU) for more information.

Comment: where should I put register_nav_menus(
    array(
        'menu_1' => 'Menu name #1',
        'menu_2' => 'Menu name #2'
    )
); in functions.php?

Comment: If you got your answer, please feel free to upvote my answer and/or mark as the correct answer. This way you save time from other stackoverflow users :)

Comment: I mean, where should I put that code inside the functions.php? In the top or in the last line of the code?

Comment: doesn't matter. you can place it in any place.

Comment: ok. i got it. btw, what file do you mean in theme files? what is the exact name?

Comment: what @MerianosNikos Nikos means by `theme files` is to put the second bit of code INSIDE the theme files, in the specific place you want them to appear. for example if you want it in the footer , try `footer.php`... and please accept the answer by clicking on the small `v` beside it ..

Comment: That's right. He has to put it into the location that the menu should be appear.

Comment: Ok, let say i put wp_nav_menu(
    array(
        'menu' => 'Project Nav'
    )
); - Project Nav is my menu name 1? (example)

Comment: I get an error.. the navigation doesn't show and when i put <?php .... ?> in this code wp_nav_menu(
    array(
        'menu' => 'menu_1'
    )
); i receive an error like this Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ''About'' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING), expecting ')' in C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress1\wp-content\themes\fanwood\header.php on line 98

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php register_nav_menu( 'menu-id-1', 'Menu Label1' ); ?> 

<?php register_nav_menu( 'menu-id-2', 'Menu Label2' ); ?>


<?php register_nav_menu( 'menu-id-3', 'Menu Label3' ); ?>
```

put this in your 'functions.php' file

Comment: only that script? it is not necessarily to add another script? so if i add that script it is automatically have a three menus right?

Comment: yes you will get 3 menus using this.

and to call them you have to use
wp_nav_menu( array(''theme_location'  => 'menu-id-1') );
wp_nav_menu( array(''theme_location'  => 'menu-id-2') );
wp_nav_menu( array(''theme_location'  => 'menu-id-3') );

Comment: where should i place that script?

Comment: You can add this 
" wp_nav_menu( array(''theme_location' => 'menu-id-1') ); "

anywhere in the template where you want to call that particular menu.

Comment: should i put like this <?php wp_nav_menu( array(''theme_location' => 'menu-id-1') ); ?>   ?